# if conditioning keeps passing even when string is empty in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im wondering what Im missing here, it must something obvious.

All I want is the marker not to appear if there are co-ordinates put in yet.

```
    var lat = jQuery('#latitude').val();
    var lng = jQuery('#longitude').val();

    alert(lat);
    alert(lng);

    if (lat.length != 0) {
     alert('shouldnt be happening');
     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
      parseFloat(lat),
      parseFloat(lng)
     );
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     map: map,
     position: latlng 
   });   

  }
```

Whether the input field is empty or not the `if` condition keeps passing.

I have also tried `if (lat != '') {}`

I have set the alerts to prove to myself they are empty, and as predicted they alert a blank pop up box when they are empty.

Thank you.

EDIT:

To simplify it I have entered this code, the strange thing now is that all 3 alerts are happening.

```
var lat = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#latitude').val());
var lng = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#longitude').val());
var zoom = 7;
alert(lat);
alert(lng);

if (lat.length == 0) {
    lat = 53.412;
    zoom = 6;
    alert('THERE IS NO LATITUDE SET');
}

if (lng.length == 0) {
    lng = -8.243;
    zoom = 6;
    alert('THERE IS NO LONGITUDE SET');
}

 if (lat.length != 0) {
    alert('now this shouldnt be happening');
 }
```

Comment: Could you log the length of the string and the charcode of the first character? `console.log(lat.charCodeAt(0));` It's possible your string is invisible characters

Comment: A "blank pop up box" does not prove emptiness. Proof: `alert(" \t\n\r    \r \t \x01\x02\x03\x04\x05");`

Comment: Maybe you have whitespace on the input field. Try checking the actual length and/or using [String.trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Comment: Yep, try this instead: var lat = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#latitude').val());

Comment: Thank you for the help, Ive edited the above to highlight the issue even further and strangely @StaticVoid , your code didnt work!

Comment: Apologies I am idiot!

Comment: I was giving it a value but I never included that in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use a more protective code:

```
var lat = jQuery('#latitude').val() || "";
var lng = jQuery('#longitude').val() || "";
```

Then:

```
if (lat.length != "") {
   ...
}
```

`val()` can return null in many cases, using the `|| "";` you get sure you have a defined value of the expected type at var initialization.

Also, I think it's better to replace val() with:

```
attr("value")
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the Javascript Shorthand coding techniques.

When you get a variable,

```
var lat = jQuery('#latitude').val();
var lng = jQuery('#longitude').val();
```

When you need to check its length you need to first check for these conditions,

> null, undefined and empty

So you can check like,

```
if( lat !== null && lat !== undefined && lat !== "" && lat.length !== 0 ) {
    //do something
}
```

Its a good practice to use "Strict Equality" when you check for equality.

The Shorthand method to check the above conditions is,

```
if( lat || "" ){ 
    //Do Something
}
```

I have a collection of JavaScript Shorthand Techniques you can refer. [Link](https://github.com/ramchiranjeevi/JavaScript/blob/master/Javascript%20Shorthand%20conding%20Techniques)